# How to get automatically "origdate" with the date in a citation?

Tags: biblatex

I am using `authoryear` with `biblatex`.

When, for instance, I type `\parencite[p.6]{gusfield2009}`, I get :

> (Gusfield, 2009, p.6)

How to get also the `origdate` entry in the citation in order to have :

> (Gusfield, [1981] 2009, p. 6)

Comment: `authorstyle` is not a valid `biblatex` style, do you mean `authoryear`? By default, the `origyear` (`origdate`) is not displayed in the bibliography either, where do you want it to appear (what `mergedate` option, if any, do you use?)?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake (it is fixed now). I don't have specific mergedate option (in fact, I don't what mergedate is for the moment, I am still new..)

Comment: For `mergedate` read [this file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/50-style-authoryear.pdf).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you only want the `origdate` in citations, you need

```
\documentclass[a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author  = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title   = {An Old Work},
  date    = {2010},
  edition = {5},
  origdate = {1981},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \printorigdate
     \setunit*{\addspace}
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{test} and \parencite[6]{test}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

---

### Edit

The following approach incorporates the `origdate` into more cite commands and the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,mergedate=maximum]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author  = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title   = {An Old Work},
  date    = {2010},
  edition = {5},
  origdate = {1981},
}
@book{testn,
  author  = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title   = {A New Work},
  date    = {2013},
}
@book{testm,
  author  = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title   = {A Very Old Work},
  date    = {2000},
  edition = {8},
  origdate = {1882},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeorigyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{origyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{test} and \parencite[6]{test}.
  And \parencite[6]{testn} is nice and \textcite{testm} was written in \citeyear{testm}.

  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives
[image]

Comment: Another question : Is there a way to get also automatically the original date with the date while using `\citeyear` ? In order to have for instance : [1981]2010 (Or do you think I should better do it manually ?)

Comment: For now, I don't work on the bibliography. I might use another style for the References. However, ideally the original date would be also before the date as follows : Ordsmith, Walter [1981] 2010, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Just to complete the topic, what is the command to display origyear, since you also mentioned it ?

Comment: @Leo The lower level command is `\printfield{origyear}` (do not use this in your document though). I have updated the answer to provide `\citeorigyear` which cites the `origyear` (without brackets or anything around it). Alternatively, there is the quite cumbersome `\citefield{testm}{origyear}`.

Comment: Using TeX Live 2018, the first MVE generates some warnings but it works and the second MVE doesn't work. @moewe, what versions of `pdflatex`, `biblatex` and `biber` did you use?

Comment: @asr The answer has been updated for the current version of `biblatex`

Comment: @moewe, please note that the parentheses are missing from e.g.`\textcite{testn}` in your solution which incorporates the `origdate` into more cite commands (I didn't test the other solution).

Comment: @asr Yeah, it shouldn't be doing that. Apparently `\setunit*` didn't quite work as intended. This should be fixed now.

Comment: @asr The behaviour of `\setunit*` after `\printdate` was a bug and will be fixed in the next `biblatex` release: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/a4d0e9efa2cf16b76b7aebe4c04bbb1e58913fe8. In the meantime the code above should work as expected (and should continue to do so even after the update).

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the biblatex-chicago package, which comes with styles supporting `origdate`.

So

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{hume_1751_enquiry,
    origdate = {1751},
    date = {1975-06-12},
    author = {Hume, David},
    title = {An Enquiry Concerning the Principles of Morals},
    booktitle = {Enquiries Concerning Human Understanding and
        Concerning the Principles of Morals},
    editor = {Selby-Bigge, L. A. and Nidditch, P. H.},
    annotation = {Selby-Bigge and Nidditch's 1975 edition is
        based off a collection of Hume's essays postumously
        published in 1777. Hume's ``An Equiry Concerning the
        Principles of Morals" was first published in 1751.},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    location = {New York},
    edition = {3},
    isbn = {978-0-19-824536-0}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate,
    backend=biber,
    sorting=nyt,
    backref=true,
    alldates=iso8601,
    cmsdate=both,
    annotation=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem \autocite[179]{hume_1751_enquiry}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Will result in

[image: cmsdate both]

The `cmsdate` option controls how `origdate` and `date` are displayed both in the citation and in the reference list. My own preference is to use `cmsdate=on` which has the effect of eliminating the `date` field in the citation, but nevertheless displays both dates in the reference entry (the `date` is moved to the end of the entry):

[image: cmsdate on]

The Chicago Manual of Style, if that's the style guide you want to follow, [specifies not using "p." to preface page numbers](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html). But if you wanted to you could use ...

```
\autocite[p. 179]{hume_1751_enquiry}.
```

... to return ...

> (Hume [1751] 1975, p. 179)

### Update

Better, however, would be to add the following code to your preamble to insert "p." and "pp." automatically (in lieu of manually specifying it) ...

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
```

... as moewe suggests in the comments.

Comment: If one wants to get the page prefix back in `biblatex-chicago`, one should probably better use `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}`, `\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}`. Inserting the "p."/"pp." manually should be a thing of the past with `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe that's definitely the better approach. I've updated the main post accordingly. Thanks for the code!