# How to cite first edition in brackets [chevrons] next to the published version in latex / jabref?

Tags: citing, jabref, biblatex-chicago

I am a Latex beginner and need help please:

I am writing my thesis with latex and have a problem with a specific citation:
I have to use Harvard style (insert citation) and give the following information of a book in the bibliography:

ex: 
Fanon, Frantz (2005[1961]): *The Wretched of the Earth*. New York: Grove Press

[1961] means first published in 1961. But Jabref displays it on the compiled pdf like this:

Fanon, Frantz: *The Wretched of the Earth*. 1961 Ndr. 2005 
(Ndr. means reprint in German, my thesis is in German)

I need the first published info in these [brackets] and the publisher at the end. I already tried to find the way to do it in numerous forums and a Latex guide. I tried: origdate = {1961} in Jabref but it doesn't work, it just does: 
1961 Ndr. 2005

I would be so grateful for help! Have a good day :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short, compilable code you use to create your bibliography at the moment? Please do not forget to add an bib entry to your question.  Welche Dokumentklasse benutzen Sie?

Comment: Does this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134644/105447 or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142999/105447 help?

Comment: For help creating a short, compilable document, see [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Are you actually using `biblatex-chicago` because the output you describe getting is not like the output I got when I used that package a while ago. The style manual does get updated, and I'm no longer using the package, but I would be surprised if it produced that output unless you are using the note variant, perhaps. Note that 'Harvard' is unfortunately used to refer to any of rather many different author-year styles, so is not very specific at all.