# Origdate citation within biblatex-philosophy

Tags: biblatex-philosophy

I need to print the original publication date according to Harvard standards, namely that year into brackets next to the reprint date. I followed [moewe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134644/how-to-get-automatically-origdate-with-the-date-in-a-citation) which mostly works fine:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=false,numbers=endperiod,headsepline=1pt,DIV=classic]{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-classic,scauthors=bib]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\volnumpunct}{\addthinspace}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{(#1)}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{pp. #1}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{: }
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:scauthorsbib}{\usebibmacro{bbx:scswitch}}{}%
  #1}

%moewe:

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeorigyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{origyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as you can see, I use `biblatex-philosophy` which treats `origdate` as being a field related to translation data:

> The following [orig*] fields can hold the translation or the original
> edition data. They are preceded by the string “trans.” or “orig. ed.”,
> respectively according to the origfields=trans (default) or
> origfields=origed option (see below). Note that the origdate/transdate
> field is needed in order to print these fields.

How can I get rid of those strings and simply have a dot at the end of the location field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't plan on using the `origtitle`, `origlocation`, `origpublisher` fields (and they are deprecated in favour of the `related` feature anyway), you can issue `origfields=none,`. (If you need them back for a particular entry, you can set the option `origed` on a per-entry basis.)

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=false,numbers=endperiod,headsepline=1pt,DIV=classic]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=philosophy-classic,
  origfields=none,
  scauthors=bib,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\volnumpunct}{\addthinspace}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{pp. #1}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:scauthorsbib}{\usebibmacro{bbx:scswitch}}{}%
  #1}


\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeorigyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{origyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author   = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title    = {An Old Work},
  date     = {2010},
  edition  = {5},
  origdate = {1981},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{test}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Ordsmith, Walter [1981] (2010), An Old Work, 5th ed.]